# Cache Pagination CakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

The pagination code above works perfectly fine on CakePHP 2.0. But not in CakePHP 3.0.

I was trying to cache my pagination query result. This code below will show the first page of my result. However, when I clicked on page two. I got this error below. Can anyone please advise how can I cache each individual page no(view)? What am I missing?

Notice (8): Undefined index: pageCount [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 630]

Notice (8): Undefined index: count [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 556]

Notice (8): Undefined index: perPage [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 559]

```
            $classlist = Cache::read('classrooms_'.$schoolid,'schoolclasslist'); 

            if(!$classlist) {                

                        $classlist = $this->paginate(
                        $this->Classrooms
                             ->find()
                             ->hydrate(false)
                             ->select(['id','name','school_id','created','modified'])
                             ->where (['school_id' => $schoolid])
                              ->cache('classrooms_'.$schoolid,'schoolclasslist')
                        );

            } 

            $this->set('classrooms', $classlist);
```

Comment: `The pagination code above` There's nothing above this line. `works perfectly fine on CakePHP 2.0. But not in CakePHP 3.0`. Please show the full controller action + beforeFilter.

Comment: did you load many model in function? i found this errors when i was load many model.